# How to host Django1.3.1 in Apache2.2?

Tags: python, windows, django, apache2, django-wsgi

I am Using python 2.7.2,Django 1.3.1, Apache 2.2.22 on WindowsXP(win32). By the documentation i found [here](http://pradyumnajoshi.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/setting-up-mod_wsgi-for-apache-and-django-on-windows/) i did the step by step, but when the directory section is given

```
   `Alias /media/ C:/Programs/TestDjango/mysite/media/
    <Directory C:/Programs/TestDjango/mysite/media/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / C:/Programs/TestDjango/mysite/apache/django.wsgi
    <Directory C:/Programs/TestDjango/mysite/apache>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>`
```

and restarted the Apache, On opening localhost/mysite i get a Microsoft Visual C++ Library runtime error, and the Apache error log shows "Caught ImproperlyConfigured while rendering: Error loading pyodbc module: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed."....My Django app run in WAMP but wish to know where did i go wrong using Apache2.2.22 alone. Followed many Django documentation but still the same, Please to help me find where did i go wrong. thanks

(identation was fixed by guettli)

Comment: Have you verified that mod_wsgi is properly loading in your standalone installation of Apache?

Comment: @jlmcdonald: yes mod_wsgi is loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it solved, it was the version problem, as i worked with Apache 2.2.21 instead of Apache 2.2.22, its working. i followed the step in this [link](http://sdtidbits.blogspot.in/2009/10/deploying-django-application-on-apache.html).

Install Python 2.7.2, Django 1.3.1 and Apache2.2.21
Install the modwsgi module.

The module file will be named something like mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py26-2.6.so [get mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/list/).

Copy it to the modules directory of the Apache installation. E.g., C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/modules.

Rename it to mod_wsgi.so. Right click--> properties click Unblock and apply

Open Apache's http.conf file.

Add the line LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so before all the other LoadModule entries.

Configure Apache for your Django project by adding the following to end of http.conf:

```
# Static content
    Alias /media/ C:/Programs/TestDjango/mysite/media/

    <Directory C:/Programs/TestDjango/mysite/media/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

# Django dynamic content

    WSGIScriptAlias / C:/Programs/TestDjango/mysite/apache/django.wsgi

    <Directory C:/Programs/TestDjango/mysite/apache>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>`
```

Where icardtest is the Django project root. The paths below icardtest will be specific to your project. This configuration serves all static media via the URL space /media/ and all the rest via WSGI and Django.
        Create a file django.wsgi and add the following to it:

```
      ` import os
        import sys

        sys.path.append('C:/Programs/TestDjango')
        os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

        import django.core.handlers.wsgi
        application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()`
```

Restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Your error has to do with your python setup, not Apache.

`Error loading pyodbc module: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.`

This means that the Python you are using with Apache cannot load the `pyodbc` module. Once you fix this error, you can proceed.

Comment: but this same Python and Django works fine in the Django's built-in server and with WAMP but not with Standalone Apache, so i don't think there is error in python setup.